2 identical red balls and 3 identical black balls in 5 different boxes, each box contain at most 2 balls, find number of combination.
I try to do:
$$
\frac{9!-5\times 4 \times 3 \times 7!}{4!\times 2!\times 3!}
$$
and get 210
however I wrote a python program to validate my answer:
import itertools
def count_ways_pigeonhole(red_balls, black_balls, boxes, max_balls_per_box):
    exists = set()
    def find_combinations(red_balls, black_balls,block):
        base = ['red' for _ in range(red_balls)] + ['black' for _ in range(black_balls)] + block
        combs = itertools.permutations(base, len(base))
        for comb in combs:
            exists.add(tuple(comb))
    find_combinations(red_balls, black_balls,['block' for _ in range(boxes - 1)])
    #validate
    validate_combinations = []
    for comb in exists:
        s = ' '.join(comb)
        s = s.split('block')
        s = [i.strip().split(' ') for i in s]
        for i in s:
            if len(i) > max_balls_per_box:
                break
        else:
            validate_combinations.append(comb)
    
    for i in range(len(validate_combinations)):
        for j in validate_combinations[:i] + validate_combinations[i+1:]:
            if validate_combinations[i] == j:
                print('error')
    for i in validate_combinations[:20]:
        print(i)
    return len(validate_combinations)


red_balls = 2
black_balls = 3 
boxes = 5
max_balls_per_box = 2



print(count_ways_pigeonhole(red_balls, black_balls, boxes, max_balls_per_box))

and get 510.
I don't know how to validate my answer.

Edit
First, see the comment that I left, following the answer of Robert Shore.

There may well be a more elegant approach than the one that I am taking.  I regard the question as tricky, and requiring an understanding of partitioning an integer.
The number $~2~$ (red balls) can be partitioned as either

$~2~$

$~1 + 1.~$


Given that no box contain more than $~2~$ balls, the satisfying partitions of $~3~$ (black balls) are

$~2 + 1.~$

$~1 + 1 + 1.~$


So, you have $~2 \times 2 = 4~$ separate cases to enumerate.
Edit
My guess is that this represents the problem composer's intent.  Otherwise, why pose a problem that involves such small numbers as $~2~$ and $~3~?$
Let $~N_1, N_2, N_3, N_4~$ denote the respective enumerations in Case 1, Case 2, Case 3, and Case 4, below.
Then, the final compuation will be
$$N_1 + N_2 + N_3 + N_4.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~2 ~\text{Red,} ~2 + 1 ~\text{Black}}$
The $~2~$ red, $~2~$ black and $~1~$ black can be thought of as three separate entities that must be assigned $~3~$ different boxes.
Because these entities are different, the order of assignment of these boxes is relevant.
So,
$$N_1 = \frac{5!}{(5-3)!} = 60.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~2 ~\text{Red,} ~1 + 1 + 1 ~\text{Black}}$
Similar to case 1, you have $~4~$ distinct entities.
So,
$$N_2 = \frac{5!}{(5-4)!} \times \frac{1}{3!} = 20.$$
In the above computation, the $~\dfrac{1}{3!}~$ factor accommodates that the order that the black balls are assigned to the boxes is irrelevant, because each box receives exactly 1 black ball.

$\underline{\text{Case 3:} ~1 + 1 ~\text{Red,} ~2 + 1 ~\text{Black}}$
The black balls can be distributed in $~\displaystyle \frac{5!}{(5-2)!} = 20~$ ways.
Then, since the box that received 1 black ball can also receive a red ball, there are $~4~$ boxes available to receive the red balls.
So, the second factor is
$$\frac{4!}{(4-2)!} \times \frac{1}{2!} = 6.$$
Therefore,
$$N_3 = 20 \times 6 = 120.$$

$\underline{\text{Case 4:} ~1 + 1 ~\text{Red,} ~1 + 1 + 1 ~\text{Black}}$
Similar to the analysis in the other cases,
$$N_4 = \binom{5}{2} \times \binom{5}{3} = 100.$$

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$
$$N_1 + N_2 + N_3 + N_4$$
$$= 60 + 20 + 120 + 100 = 300.$$

I think it don't cover 1 black and 1 red in 1 box case, do it?

@laoyaobainian Yes, it certainly does cover that.  However, the organization is not by what goes into box-1, what goes into box-2, and so forth.  Instead, the organization is by combining satisfactory integer partitions of $~2~$ with satisfactory integer partitions of $~3.~$  I suggest that you read the answer more carefully, and try to understand my thinking.  Then, if you can find an explicit flaw in my thinking, please leave another comment.  For example, your first comment is far too vague for me to directly respond to.

@laoyaobainian If you can find an explicit complete distribution of all $~5~$ balls into the boxes that you think that I have overlooked (or counted more than once), please specify the complete distribution, exactly.  Then, I will have a specific issue to investigate.

It is obvious that some of the boxes can have $0$ balls, else the clause "at most $2$ balls" makes no sense.
Assuming that order within boxes doesn't matter, we can simply list the patterns possible, and permute them
$$\boxed{RR}\boxed{BB}\boxed{B}\boxed{0}\boxed{0}: \frac{5!}{2!} = 60$$
$$\boxed{RR}\boxed{B}\boxed{B}\boxed{B}\boxed{0}: \frac{5!}{3!} = 20$$
$$\boxed{R}\boxed{R}\boxed{BB}\boxed{B}\boxed{0}: \frac{5!}{2!} = 60$$
$$\boxed{R}\boxed{R}\boxed{B}\boxed{B}\boxed{B}: \frac{5!}{2!3!} = 10$$
$$\boxed{RB}\boxed{RB}\boxed{B}\boxed{0}\boxed{0}: \frac{5!}{2!2!} = 30$$
$$\boxed{RB}\boxed{R}\boxed{BB}\boxed{0}\boxed{0} : \frac{5!}{2!} = 60$$
$$\boxed{RB}\boxed{R}\boxed{B}\boxed{B}\boxed{0}: \frac{5!}{2!} = 60$$
Alas, this gives a total of just $\boxed{300}$

$\underline{\mathtt{ADDED}}$
If we assume that order of colors within boxes matters, it will be
$$60+20+60+10+4\cdot30+2\cdot60+2\cdot60 = \boxed{510}$$
which tallies with your Python answer, but I don't see where it has been specified that order within boxes matters.

First assume that both red balls go into the same box.  There are $5$ possible choices for that box.  The number of ways to distribute the black balls is the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=3$, subject to the constraint that $\forall i~(x_i \leq 2)$.  Stars and bars tells us there are $\binom 63=20$ unconstrained solutions to this equation, of which $4$ are forbidden because they place all three black balls in the same box.  Thus, there are $16$ permissible ways to distribute the black balls, given the condition on the red balls.  This accounts for $5 \cdot 16=80$ combinations.
Now assume the red balls are in two different boxes.  Those boxes can be selected in $\binom 52=10$ ways.
If both of those boxes also have a black ball, there are $3$ ways to place the remaining black ball in a box.
If one of the boxes containing a red ball also contains a black ball, there are $2$ ways to select that box.  The distribution of the remaining black balls is the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=2,$ which is $\binom 42=6.$
If neither box that contains a red ball also contains a black ball, then the distribution of the black balls is the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+x_3=3$, subject to the constraint that $\forall i~(x_i \leq 2).$  There are $\binom 52=10$ unconstrained solutions to this equation, of which $3$ are forbidden because they place all three black balls in a single box.  Thus, there are $7$ permitted solutions to this equation.
We therefore have $10(3+2 \cdot 6+7)=220$ possible distributions with the red balls in two different boxes.  Adding this to the $80$ solutions in which both red balls are in the same box, we have a total of $300$ possible solutions.

+1 (also), because your answer employed Stars and Bars, and my answer did not.  In my opinion, this implies that for similar problems involving larger numbers, the problem solver should consider using your approach as a guide, rather than my approach.  That is, on the one hand, Stars and Bars will generalize nicely.  On the other hand, in my answer, as the numbers get bigger, the cross-product of the number of distinct satisfying integer partitions will grow very quickly.

Probably not the most straightforward approach, but a nice exercise with generating functions.
Let
$$
f(x,y)=1+x+y+xy+x^2+y^2
$$
be the generating function for the configurations of one box, where the exponent of $x$ represents the number of red balls in the box and the exponent of $y$ represents the number of black balls in the box.
Therefore, the generating function of all the possible configurations of five boxes with 0, 1 or 2 balls (regardless of the color and the total number of balls) is
$$
g(x,y) = f(x,y)^5 = (1+x+y+xy+x^2+y^2)^5.
$$
In other words, the coefficient of $x^p y^q$ in $g(x,y)$ represents the number of configurations of 5 boxes for which

the number of balls in each box is 0, 1 or 2;
counting all five boxes, the total number of red balls is $p$ and the total number of black balls is $q$.

Then, the configurations we are interested in are represented by the term $x^2y^3$, and we need to compute its coefficient.
After some algebra, we can show
$$
g(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^5\sum_{m=0}^k\sum_{n=0}^{5-k}\sum_{l=0}^{5-k}\binom{5}{k}\binom{k}{m}\binom{5-k}{n}\binom{5-k}{l}x^{n+l}y^{5+2m-k-n}
$$
and, thus, the number of configurations we are after is
$$
N=\sum\binom{5}{k}\binom{k}{m}\binom{5-k}{n}\binom{5-k}{l}
$$
where the sum is over all $k,m,n,l$ such that

$n+l=2$
$5+2m-k-n=3 \implies k+n-2m=2$
$0 \le k \le 5$
$0 \le m \le k$
$0\le n\le 5-k$
$0\le l\le 5-k$.

Therefore (the 4-tuples below the braces are $(k,m,n,l)$)
\begin{align}
N &= \underbrace{\binom{5}{2}\binom{2}{0}\binom{3}{0}\binom{3}{2}}_{(2,0,0,2)} + \underbrace{\binom{5}{1}\binom{1}{0}\binom{4}{1}\binom{4}{1}}_{(1,0,1,1)}
+ \underbrace{\binom{5}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}\binom{2}{1}}_{(3,1,1,1)} \\
&\qquad+ \underbrace{\binom{5}{0}\binom{0}{0}\binom{5}{2}\binom{5}{0}}_{(0,0,2,0)}
+ \underbrace{\binom{5}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{0}}_{(2,1,2,0)} \\
&= 10\cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot 3 + 5\cdot 1 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 + 10\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 + 1\cdot 1 \cdot 10 \cdot 1 + 10\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 1 \\
&= 30 + 80 + 120 + 10 + 60 \\
&= 300.
\end{align}

Thanks every one, and there is corrected validation code:
import itertools
def count_ways_pigeonhole(red_balls, black_balls, boxes, max_balls_per_box):
    exists = set()
    def find_combinations(red_balls, black_balls,block):
        base = ['red' for _ in range(red_balls)] + ['black' for _ in range(black_balls)] + block
        combs = itertools.permutations(base, len(base))
        for comb in combs:
            exists.add(tuple(comb))
    find_combinations(red_balls, black_balls,['block' for _ in range(boxes - 1)])
    #validate
    validate_combinations = []
    for comb in exists:
        s = ' '.join(comb)
        s = s.split('block')
        s = [i.strip().split(' ') for i in s]
        for i in s:
            if len(i) > max_balls_per_box:
                break
        else:
            tmp =[sorted(i) for i in s]
            if tmp not in validate_combinations:
                validate_combinations.append(tmp)
    
    for i in range(len(validate_combinations)):
        for j in validate_combinations[:i] + validate_combinations[i+1:]:
            if validate_combinations[i] == j:
                print('error')
    for i in validate_combinations[:20]:
        print(i)
    return len(validate_combinations)


red_balls = 2
black_balls = 3 
boxes = 5
max_balls_per_box = 2



print(count_ways_pigeonhole(red_balls, black_balls, boxes, max_balls_per_box))
```


First decide whether the 2 red balls are in same box (else in separate box), then decide whether there exists 2 black balls in same box (else all in separate box).
$$
\color{red}{\binom{5}1}\left[\color{blue}{\binom{4}1\binom{3}1} + 
\color{green}{\binom{4}3}\right] + \color{purple}{\binom{5}2}\left[\color{blue}{\binom{3}1\binom{4}1} + \color{green}{\binom{5}3}\right]\\
= 5[4*3+4] + 10[3*4+10]\\
= 300
$$
red balls are in same box : $\color{red}{\binom{5}1}$
red balls are in seperate box : $\color{purple}{\binom{5}2}$
there exists 2 black balls in same box: $\color{blue}{\binom{4}1\binom{3}1}$ or $\color{blue}{\binom{3}1\binom{4}1}$ depending on first decision
all black balls in separate box: $\color{green}{\binom{4}3}$ or $\color{green}{\binom{5}3}$ depending on first decision
